# How to parse a numerical string to decimal and convert it back to the string without any loss?

Tags: c#

How to parse a numerical string `input` to decimal `number` and convert it back to the string without any loss?

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "-1.234.567.890,123456789012345678901234567890";
        var ci = new CultureInfo("id-ID");

        decimal number = decimal.Parse(input, NumberStyles.Number, ci);
        string output = number.ToString("N", ci);

        Console.WriteLine(output == input);// produces False

    }
}
```

Here I am learning how to parse and convert with the simplest way.

Comment: It's valid in the `id-ID` culture.

Comment: I don't think there would be a 100% reliable implementation for that which does not keep the original string around. For instance, if you have an arbitrary number of trailing zeroes after the comma, there's no way to get the original string back without at least keeping the information about how many zeroes there were. Same with other aspects. You'd be better off creating a new custom type that holds the original string and also the parsed number. Similar to how the `URI` type works.

Comment: Note that the `"N"` format specifier only uses 2 decimal places by default. Either specify the number of decimal places explicitly, or just use `number.ToString(ci)`. Also note that your original string contains trailing zeros in the decimal part, which for a number are redundant. If you want/need to get those redundant zeros as well, you will have to specifiy decimal places together with the `"N"` format specifier. That said, it seems that decimal cannot hold your number with 29 relevant decimal places to begin with :-(

Comment: Your number is 40 digits long.  `decimal` has precision to 28-29 significant digits.  You are going to lose precision.

Comment: As Amy said about precision lost, you then could store decimal value separately. For instance, BigInteger could be of help (`System.Numerics`). In fact, you could create your own data type to store such numbers (with operators overloading).

Comment: I mean.. you could split the input by the `,`. Then just replace the `.` with `string.empty` and try converting those.. More work, but it might be what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a class of `MyType` to hold your number and split the input into the two different sections.

You might have trouble if you plan on using these numbers for arithmetic. You probably have to overload the arithmetic operations and implement your own.

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Mine
    string input = "-1.234.567.890,123456789012345678901234567890";
    string left = input.Split(',')[0].Replace(".", string.Empty);
    string right = input.Split(',')[1];

    MyType myInput = new MyType(
        int.Parse(left, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign), 
        BigInteger.Parse(right, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign));

    Console.WriteLine(input);
    Console.WriteLine(myInput);

    Console.WriteLine(input == myInput.ToString());

    // Yours
    string input2 = "-1.234.567.890,123456789012345678901234567890";
    var ci = new CultureInfo("id-ID");

    decimal number = decimal.Parse(input2, NumberStyles.Number, ci);
    string output = number.ToString("N", ci);

    Console.WriteLine(input2);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    Console.WriteLine(output == input2);// produces False
}

public class MyType
{
    public int whole;
    public BigInteger deci;

    public MyType(int whole, BigInteger deci)
    {
        this.whole = whole;
        this.deci = deci;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1}", string.Format("{0:#,####}", whole)
                     .Replace(',' ,'.'), deci);
    }
}

// Mine
-1.234.567.890,123456789012345678901234567890
-1.234.567.890,123456789012345678901234567890
True
// Yours
-1.234.567.890,123456789012345678901234567890
-1.234.567.890,12
False
```

Answer (score 1):

[`decimal` can store only up to 28-29 significant digits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/floating-point-types-table).

For numbers with more digits you can try libraries such as BigFloat or BigDecimal.